# Getting exception System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyListBoxItem'.' how to handle it?

Tags: c#, winforms

The full exception message:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyListBoxItem'.
  Source=Image Crop
  StackTrace:
   at Image_Crop.Form1.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Csharp Projects\Image Crop\Form1.cs:line 387
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.RefreshItems()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnDisplayMemberChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DisplayMember(String value)
```

Screenshot of the item content as string:

[exception message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNtah.jpg)

and this is a screenshot of the item object.  how do I get access to the Message?

[item object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d43ch.jpg)

The code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
            MyListBoxItem mm = (MyListBoxItem)item;
            var val = mm.Message;
            int index = val.LastIndexOf(",");
            string you = val.Substring(index + 1);
            if (File.Exists(you))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(you);
            }
        }
```

The exception message error is on the line:

```
MyListBoxItem mm = (MyListBoxItem)item;
```

I tried to cast it to string but it didn't work.

This is the MyListBoxItem class in Form1:

```
public class MyListBoxItem
    {
        public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: "I tried to cast it to string but it didn't work" - what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it seems that `ListBox.SelectedItem` is a `String` object. Casting is only meant for similar types (such as Collection/List, int/long, char/byte, etc). You cannot cast a string to an object, because C# runtime, and the compiler, do not understand how to deserialize the string and produce the object.

You will need to add a method that can construct a `MyListBoxItem` object from a string. The naming convention in C# is: `MyListBoxItem.Parse`.